# How to reset a PHP environment?

Tags: php

At some point in my code, I want to undo everything that has been made and simulate a fresh start in some file.php.

Example: Unsetting all variables, all functions, all classes, etc.

Is there a way to do this?

---

### DETAILS

I have a framework that redirects all the requests to `index.php` but i want to roll some tests on it (testing the framework itself!). So i need to write a controller to access `/test/index.php` and it will start including the files and testing the functions and stuff. The thing is, I will get errors if the files are already included, the classes already exists, etc.

Comment: closed with not even comments on how to improve the question? D:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just call a new page via `header( 'Location: http://domain.com/file.php' )`

Comment: there is a rewrite leading all requests to index.php

Comment: Just call the URL that is currently called, you can get the request path via `$_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URL' ]`

Comment: With `header( 'Location: {absolute url}' );`

e.g. `header( 'Location: http://my.domain.com' . $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URL' ] );`

Comment: it would just get rewrited to `/index.php/$1` again =/

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your edit in your first post yet. I don't see why you'd need an environment reset, what keeps you off of testing with your current controller system? Just build a TestController and give it some methods to play with

Comment: yea...i guess you're right. i'll just think of another strategy then. thanks (: